# How to set up the PEM file for a secure PYTHON websocket server?

Tags: python, ssl, websocket, pem

Im creating a websocket server in PYTHON

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("localhost.pem")
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(localhost_pem)

start_server = websockets.serve(
    hello, "localhost", 8765, ssl=ssl_context
)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

This is the client

```
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl
import websockets

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("localhost.pem")
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(localhost_pem)

async def hello():
    uri = "wss://psXXXXXX.dreamhostps.com:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(
        uri, ssl=ssl_context
    ) as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        print(f"> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

I start the python server in my host provider by running the server python file and there's no problem at all
But when I try to run my python client the SERVER refuses the connection. Everything seems to be right but Im not quite sure how to set up this localhost.pem for my VPS server in dreamhost.

Any guileline about how to do this would be much appreciated.